# Programmaticaly How to provide consecutive arbitary number of whitespace characters within MultiBinding StringFromat?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, string-formatting, multibinding

Please examine following code snippet :

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtBox_CommandInfo"  Style="{DynamicResource MetroTextBox}" IsReadOnly="True" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="This is a textbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,236,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="154" Width="780" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}      {1}        {2} {3}&#x20;{4} {5}    {6}          {7}          {8}        {9}        {10}&#x0a;{11}">
                <Binding  Path="No" />
                <Binding  Path="SelectedType" />
                <Binding  Path="IgnoreSignature"/>
                <Binding  Path="IgnoreRelString"/>
                <Binding  Path="DirectDL"/>
                <Binding  Path="LegacySC" />
                <Binding  Path="SelectedDVName"/>
                <Binding  Path="SelectedHCName"/>
                <Binding  Path="SelectedSCName"/>
                <Binding  Path="SCRelease"/>
                <Binding  Path="DALName"/>
                <Binding  Path="PreviousLogs"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

Here I had to hard-code number of consecutive white-space characters  whenever I wanted to format the spaces between bind parameters.

- Using `&#x20;` (Code for white-space) ,Can we format the string in **programmatical/convenient** manner(with tricky code) rather than hard-coding(typing) repetitive characters(number of consecutive white spaces that we want).

My assumption like :

`<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}[&#x20;,4]{1}[&#x20;,8]{2}{3}{4}[&#x20;,6]{5}{6}[&#x20;,10]{7}{8}{9}{10}&#x0a;{11}"`

- Therefore is there any valid mechanism under WPF/XAML MultiBinding StringFormat to provide that, for a given character or set of characters "***How many number of consecutive characters or how many repetition of characters should be generated*** ?"

Means Rather than typing required white spaces like this:

`<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}      {1}   {2}" />`

Alternative/Programmatical/Convenient but assumed mechanism(to provide how many number of whitespaces we want) like this:

`<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}[Character/s,Number of Repetition]{1}[Character/s,Number of Repetition]{2}" />
<!-- Assumed code like -->
<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}[&#x20,8]{1}[&#x20,10]{2}" />`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a whitespace argument and pad it:

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{12,5}{1}{12,5}{2}{12,1}{3}{12,1}{4}{12,1}{5}{12,4}{6}{12,8}{7}{12,8}{8}{12,8}{9}{12,4}{10}&#x0a;{11}">
    <Binding Path="No" />
    <Binding Path="SelectedType" />
    <Binding Path="IgnoreSignature"/>
    <Binding Path="IgnoreRelString"/>
    <Binding Path="DirectDL"/>
    <Binding Path="LegacySC" />
    <Binding Path="SelectedDVName"/>
    <Binding Path="SelectedHCName"/>
    <Binding Path="SelectedSCName"/>
    <Binding Path="SCRelease"/>
    <Binding Path="DALName"/>
    <Binding Path="PreviousLogs"/>
    <Binding Path="SomeBindingPathThatDoesNotExist" FallbackValue=" "/>
</MultiBinding>
```

`{12}` would be your value (the fallback value which is a space), and you can pad it with `{12,x}`

A better yet solution would be padding each of the bindings. That gives you a fixed size for each binding (doesn't add a constant number of whitespaces), but it's usually what you want:

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0,10}{1,10}{2,8}(etc.)">
    <Binding Path="No" />
    <Binding Path="SelectedType" />
    <Binding Path="IgnoreSignature"/>
    <Binding Path="IgnoreRelString"/>
    <Binding Path="DirectDL"/>
    <Binding Path="LegacySC" />
    <Binding Path="SelectedDVName"/>
    <Binding Path="SelectedHCName"/>
    <Binding Path="SelectedSCName"/>
    <Binding Path="SCRelease"/>
    <Binding Path="DALName"/>
    <Binding Path="PreviousLogs"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my day :) .. generalized approach would be mechanism #1.
and alternative but specialized solution for whitespace would be #2

Comment: Jcl How did you find above solution ? any standard msdn document or link? Could you provide it ?

Comment: It's pretty standard string formatting. I'd say one of the very first things I learned in c# many many years ago

Comment: You may want to check this, then: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.1#Starting

Comment: JCL If you don't mind can you help me on this, `some of text binding` won't get affected even if I apply padding size using second mechanism you mentioned , ex - `SelectedDVName` ,`SelectedHCName` kind of binding won't get padding.

Comment: The second method specifies the "minimum padding", so if you put (for example), 10, it means the string will be at least 10 characters long (padding with whitespace). If your `SelectedDVName` value is already 10 (or more) characters long, it won't do anything. That's why I mentioned it doesn't "add whitespace", but pads the actual value. By the way, the second method is "right-aligned"... if you want it "left aligned" you should use negative values for the width (e.g., `{4,-10}`)

Comment: got it,Thank you very much.